# python のSetuptoolsがインストールできません。

Tags: python, powershell, setuptools

`Windows PowerShell`を使って`python`の`Setuptools`をインストールしようとしているものです。

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Es_kdnPUgDg

上記、youtubeを参考に、動画の手順道理に進めているのですが、なかなか上手く行かず、

```
PS C:\> python ez_setup.py
Extracting in c:\users\somasoma\appdata\local\temp\tmpqfz8v7
Now working in c:\users\somasoma\appdata\local\temp\tmpqfz8v7\setuptools-18.0.1
Installing Setuptools
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ez_setup.py", line 391, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "ez_setup.py", line 388, in main
    return _install(archive, _build_install_args(options))
  File "ez_setup.py", line 53, in _install
    if not _python_cmd('setup.py', 'install', *install_args):
  File "ez_setup.py", line 45, in _python_cmd
    return subprocess.call(args) == 0
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\subprocess.py", line 524, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\subprocess.py", line 948, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
PS C:\>
```

となってしまい。システムがファイルを見つけ出せない状態です。解決方法の分かる方、いらしましたらよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

見たところ、 ez_setup.py 44行目で指定している `sys.executable` 変数に格納されているPythonの実行ファイルを見つけられずエラーになっているようです。

以下を実行するとどのような値が表示されますか？

```
python -c "import sys; print sys.executable"
```

期待する値は `'C:\Python27\python.exe'` ですが、そうでない場合それが原因でしょう。Pythonのインストール自体がよくない手順だったのか等、その原因を調べる必要があります。

Comment: sys.executableの値は何だったのか、何をどう変更したのか、を書いてください。
同様の問題に遭遇した人がここを見て参考になるように、解決方法を共有しましょう

Comment: 申し訳ありません。。
sys.executableの値は、’C:\windows\system32\python.exe’となりました！！

あと、前のコメントが消えてしまってしまっているのですが、自分がどういう風に解決したのか忘れてしまいました。。。

初心者なものでご迷惑おかけいたします。
次回から、解決方法を共有できるよう心掛けたいと思います。
ありがとう御座いました。